# How to update an array of object in a document following unique value with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Giving the following controller:

```
MyCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(;
                     ObjectId(""+id+""),
                    {
                        $push: {"points":{   
                                             $each:[{long:long,
                                                latitude:lat,
                                                reportid:repid,
                                                timestamp:timestamp,
                                            $sort:{reportid:-1}
                                        }}

                    },
                    {
                        safe:true, upsert:true, new:true
                    },
                        function(err, model){
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    )
```

I initially have my collection like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a45fd8ddc4e1251055e197"),
    "category" : "Others",
    "name" : "edzs",
    "points" : [
            {
                    "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T15:57:30",
                    "repid" : "1609",
                    "latitude" : 45.644465,
                    "long" : 5.875074000000012
            },
            {
                    "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T14:59:30",
                    "repid" : "1608",
                    "latitude" : 45.644465,
                    "long" : 5.875074000000012
            },
            {
                    "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T14:20:30",
                    "repid" : "1606",
                    "latitude" : 45.644465,
                    "long" : 5.875074000000012
            }
]
```

After every call by my controller, I got my collections like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a45fd8ddc4e1251055e197"),
            "category" : "Others",
            "name" : "edzs",
            "points" : [
                    {
                            "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T16:30:30",
                            "repid" : "1610",
                            "latitude" : 45.654465,
                            "long" : 5.885074000000012
                    },
                    {
                    "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T15:57:30",
                    "repid" : "1609",
                    "latitude" : 45.644465,
                    "long" : 5.875074000000012
            },
    {
                    "timestamp" : "2017-03-07T15:57:30",
                    "repid" : "1609",
                    "latitude" : 45.644465,
                    "long" : 5.875074000000012
            }
]
```

My objects inside "points" are cumulated sorted by reportid every call. How can I do to avoid duplicated "reportid" value. is there any commande line in mongoose  permitting to controle reportid value in order to have unique in the array?

Comment: You can use `{
                        $addToSet: {"points":{   
                                             $each:[{long:long,
                                                latitude:lat,
                                                reportid:repid,
                                                timestamp:timestamp}]}}
                    }` to keep unique values, but you cant apply sort because sets are unordered.

Comment: Thx Veeram! Let's imagine to get sets already ordered from the call. I think that after the $addToSet applied, the result will always be ordered. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. Seems like this answer address that problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351572/how-can-i-addtoset-an-object-to-an-array-and-sort-too-using-mongodb

Comment: is there any solution other solution to do that without using $addToSet commande?I checked your link but it didn't give me answer i excepted